# User can't delete queue (AMQ229213)

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am trying to create a user in ActiveMQ Artemis with the necessary permissions to delete a queue. The user has the `deleteNonDurableQueue` permission on the queue. To delete the queue, I am using the Artemis CLI with the following command:

```
amq-broker queue delete --url url --user testuser_queue_delete_allow --password password --name queue.foo.bar
```

However, when I execute the command, Artemis responds with the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" ActiveMQSecurityException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=AMQ229213: 
User: testuser does not have permission=CREATE_ADDRESS 
for queue activemq.management.59973261-566f-4600-a0f6-1820c30f8727 
on address activemq.management.59973261-566f-4600-a0f6-1820c30f8727]
at
...
```

I believe that I don't fully understand the permission model yet.

I have given the `testuser` the necessary permissions on `activemq.management.#` (`manage`, `deleteNonDurableQueue`, ...), but it seems that the user now has permissions to delete all other queues as well. Is this correct?

Is there a way to restrict the delete permissions to only one queue?

---

**Update**:

Artemis is running inside kubernetes and configured with the [activemq-artemis-operator](https://github.com/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-operator).
I hope that the following config files are valid because i made some changes to the configuration. I updated also the queue name from `queue.name` to `queue.foo.bar`.

`/etc/login.config`:

```
activemq {
    org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule sufficient
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";
};
```

`/etc/broker.xml`:

```xml
<security-settings>
   <security-setting match="#">
      <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="testrole.queue.create.allow"/>
   </security-setting>
   <security-setting match="queue.foo.#">
      <permission type="send" roles="testrole.queue.create.allow"/>
      <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="testrole.queue.delete.allow"/>
      <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="testrole.queue.delete.allow"/>
   </security-setting>
</security-settings>
```

`/etc/artemis-users.properties`:

```
admin = password
testuser_queue_create_allow = password
testuser_queue_delete_allow = password
```

`/etc/artemis-roles.properties`:

```
admin = admin
testrole.queue.delete.allow = testuser_queue_delete_allow
testrole.queue.create.allow = testuser_queue_create_allow
```

Comment: Can you provide the `<security-settings>` from your `broker.xml` as well as the `login.config` from the broker's `etc` directory?

Comment: Are you trying to ensure that the user can't delete a queue from a messaging client or from a management client?

Comment: I updated the description and provided the config files.
What is difference between a messaging and management client ?

Comment: A management user is a user that is trying to manage the broker administratively via the [management API](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#management). This can be done through the CLI, the web console, management messages, etc. A messaging user is a user who is working with _messages_ (i.e. consuming and/or producing). In the process of working with messages the messaging user may need to create queues, delete queues, create addresses, delete addresses, etc. What kind of user is trying to delete a queue in your case?

Comment: The user should have the permissions to deletes queues that match a specific pattern (for instance `queue.foo.*`, so i guess its a management user.

I'm just a bit confused about the strict segregation. A user could have both, management and messaging permissions?

And thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Management users are akin to "administrators" and messaging users are akin to just normal "users". Management users will  use the management API to manipulate the broker whereas messaging users will simply use the API provided by their messaging client implementation. There can be overlap, but the use-cases are quite different. What exactly is your use-case?

Comment: Currently you've given your user's role the `deleteNonDurableQueue` permission. This is a permission for _messaging_ clients. However, then you're using the `queue delete` command to delete the queue. This is using the management API for which the `deleteNonDurableQueue` doesn't apply. Access to the management API via [management messages](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#using-management-message-api) (which is what the `queue delete` command uses) is configured via the `manage` permission.

Comment: I am trying to create "administrators" for specific address spaces.
AdminA should have permissions to manage all queues (create, delete) within the address space `queue.foo.a`.
AdminB should have permissions to manage all queues (create, delete) within the address space `queue.foo.b`.

Comment: I don't understand what the use of the permission `deleteNonDurableQueue` (or `deleteDurableQueue`) is if this permission is not sufficient to delete a queue?
Or is `queue delete` the wrong command?

Comment: The command `queue delete` requires permissions (`send`, `manage`, `createAdress`, `createNonDurableQueue`) on the management queue?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your use-case. That helps a lot.

Comment: The `deleteNonDurableQueue` and `deleteDurableQueue` permissions refer to _messaging_ clients, not management clients. The management API is independent normal messaging use-cases. If you want to use management commands from the CLI you do need to grant `send`, `manage`, `createAdress`, and `createNonDurableQueue` on the management queue to the role used to execute those commands since they use the management message feature I described earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the various permission defined via `security-settings` apply exclusively to *messaging* clients **except** for the `manage` permission. The `manage` permission allows a messaging client to use [management messages](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#using-management-message-api) via the management address (`activemq.management` by default) to execute management operations or inspect management attributes (e.g. message counts, etc.). The CLI operations like `delete` use management messages to accomplish their tasks. In order to use such CLI operations the user invoking the command must be in a role which has the following permissions on the management address:

- `manage` (as mentioned)
- `send`
- `createAdress`
- `createNonDurableQueue`

To be clear, the `createAdress` and `createNonDurableQueue` permissions are required so that the CLI client can use the request/reply pattern.

The downside to using `manage` permission is that it gives the client essentially unlimited ability to manage the broker. There is no way to control what management operation the client performs.

If you want to have different administrative users who have different permissions then you should not use the CLI management commands and use the web console instead and configure [role-based access control](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#role-based-authorisation-for-jmx) via `management.xml`.